# React and Material CSS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, materialize

I am using React and Material CSS.

I have a drop-down component ,like so

```
 return (
      <div>
        <label>{label}</label>
        <select {...input} className="browser-default">
          <option />
          {this.generateValues(indexes)}
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I want to use the material-css look and feel ,but this component does not seem to work if I remove the "browser-default" className. How do I get around this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `Select` initialization code into the `componentDidMount()` method.

```
componentDidMount(){
  $('select').formSelect();
}
```

The better option would be to use the Input component with type `'select'` from [MaterializeCSS React component library](https://react-materialize.github.io/#/forms).

Answer (score 0):

You can use more than one className e.g.

```
className={"browser-default another-class"}
```

Comment: What should I put as the other class name ?  If  I want the material design look

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your original question correctly... If you are using Materialize, why are you not using their syntax? Have a look here https://react-materialize.github.io/#/forms

Comment: If I don't use the className ,browser default ,the drop-down doeskin render at all ,it just displays the label.

Comment: My dependencies here in include "materialize-css": "^0.100.2","react-materialize": "^2.2.0",